# newboston Android development tutorial - displaying a list menu

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am following the newboston tutorial for Android development and I am wondering if there is a quick solution for displaying the string values without needing them to be identical to their class or activity name i.e. the string name "SystemActivity" has to be identical to its activity name for it to work. The problem is it displays as "SystemActivity" on the emulator UI and I'd rather give it a more suitable name .... "Start System".

I would appreciate any help...

Here is my code:

```
String classes [] = {"SystemActivity","DietTips","About"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String link = classes [position];
    try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.example.system." + link);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I suggest you skip this tutorial, as it shows a bad practice. Very rarely you will need to find a class by its name, and this is not the case you should be doing that. A simple typo and your app does not work.

You should modify your code to be based on indices or wrapper objects with name and type. Index based approach will generate less errors that your current one, and wrapper objects should work 100% correctly.

Index based:

```
onListItemClick(...., int position...){
    Intent i;
    switch(position){
    case 0:
        //SystemActivity
        i = new Intent(Menu.this, SystemActivity.class);
        break;
    //other cases
    }
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Wrapper based:

```
public class Wrapper<T> {
    String name;
    Class<T> type;
    public Wrapper(String n, Class<T> t){
        name =n;
        type = t;
    }
    String toString(){return name};
}

//Then pass these objects to your array adapter:
Wrapper wrapper1= new Wrapper("Start System",SystemActivity.class);
...
Wrapper[] wrappers = {wrapper1,wrapper2..}
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Wrapper>(...,wrappers,..));

onListItemClick(...){
    Wrapper clicked = wrappers[position];
    Intent i = new Intent(Menu.this, clicked.type);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper class which holds both the user friendly name and the "type" (i.e. the type name) and use a custom array adapter to map it.

It's a little more involved than simply creating a ready built adapter but it's a good idea to learn how to do this as early as you can since you'll most of the time be creating custom lists with more than one string in them which will require custom adapters and custom views.

This looks to be a good example:
http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/

If anything is unclear, let me know and I'll try to help further.